# Tab Control: How to prevent the selection from changing?

Tags: c++, winapi, tabs, tabcontrol, win32gui

My project is simple WIN32 dialog box with a tab control.
Under some condition, I want to prevent the user from changing tab. MS [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760571(v=vs.85).aspx) is quite straightforward -

> Returns TRUE to prevent the selection from changing, or FALSE to allow the selection to change.

However, this just does not work!

The code:

```css
 case WM_NOTIFY:
  if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->idFrom == IDC_DEVTABS)
  {
   if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TCN_SELCHANGING)
    return  (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    //return  (INT_PTR)OnSelChanging(hDlgTab);
   if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TCN_SELCHANGE)
    OnSelChanged(hDlgTab);
    
   return  (INT_PTR)TRUE;   
  }
```

I can see that my parent dialog box receives the message, but the tab is changing anyhow. Any idea how I can prevent the tab from changing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your control is in a dialog, as I assume it is, you need to return the value through the `DWLP_MSGRESULT` window data.

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWndDlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT, TRUE);
return TRUE;
```

The return value from the dialog procedure indicates to the dialog manager whether or not the message was handled. The actual return value for the message is provided via `DWLP_MSGRESULT`.

As always, see [Raymond's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031107-00/?p=41923) for a good discussion of this.

Comment: New location for the blog entry https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031107-00/?p=41923